# Linux distribution without GUI for start an app on boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, distribution-choice

I'm new to embedded systems/softwares and wanted to develop a video player for my PI that runs when it starts. Something like Kodi or LibreELEC.

The question I am now asking myself is that is there a Linux distro that may not have a GUI and just open a program when it starts. Best in full screen mode so that you don't recognize which Linux operating system you are using.

According to my research and maybe the best example is that Android is derived from Linux and you don't get to see it. The same with Fire OS which is derived from Android.

Comment: For embedded devices, you would typically build your own distro using buildroot or yocto. On the other hand, what keeps you from using any distro and autostart your video player?

Comment: As I said I want to avoid seeing any gui but only my application. I want it to look professional. Anyway, thanks for the two names. At least I'm getting closer to it now.

Comment: I already did a device with a debian system without GUI, even without X11, booting into a Qt framebuffer application. It's also no rocket science to add a custom splash screen to U-Boot. Setting up your own yocto feels a little more like landing on the moon.